# Position sticky, but always at viewport bottom

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

I want to make a sidebar navigation which behave a kind like `position: sticky` and `position: fixed` together.
I am unable to make a sticky element that has a dynamic height. Ideally I want to do it with CSS only.

The sidebar is after a header (which is not fixed), and I want the sidebar to stick at the top of the browser when you scroll past the header (so `position: sticky` is great for that).
But I want the bottom of my sidebar to be always at the bottom of the browser view. Like `position: fixed`.

My result so far is the following snippet:
When you are at the top of the snippet, and you scroll at the bottom of the sidebar, *Item 18* remains hidden because the sidebar go beyond the view.
If you scroll past the header in the main container, the sidebar is fine, because it has a`100vh` size.

I would love to set `bottom: 0;` to the sticky element, to be fixed at the bottom, but it only works if I set the sticky element to be `position: fixed;` and then of course it does not stick anymore at the top.

```css
.header {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 7rem;
}

.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="sticky-nav">
      <p>Item 1</p>
      <p>Item 2</p>
      <p>Item 3</p>
      <p>Item 4</p>
      <p>Item 5</p>
      <p>Item 6</p>
      <p>Item 7</p>
      <p>Item 8</p>
      <p>Item 9</p>
      <p>Item 10</p>
      <p>Item 11</p>
      <p>Item 12</p>
      <p>Item 13</p>
      <p>Item 14</p>
      <p>Item 15</p>
      <p>Item 16</p>
      <p>Item 17</p>
      <p>Item 18</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisl iaculis sem ullamcorper laoreet vel posuere urna. Sed venenatis sem quis mattis auctor. Proin a urna risus. Maecenas eu purus semper, semper nibh a, pharetra est. Nunc ultrices elit convallis tristique consequat. Phasellus placerat velit sapien, vitae rhoncus arcu ultrices at. In sodales sodales lorem, vitae efficitur arcu pulvinar ac. Nam finibus luctus luctus. Ut aliquet ullamcorper tempor. Nullam a malesuada est, rhoncus elementum nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam lobortis pulvinar est eu dignissim.

Aenean pretium enim et libero vehicula, a scelerisque enim viverra. Phasellus ullamcorper tortor ac nisl ornare, eu volutpat libero efficitur. Vivamus vitae nisi viverra, ullamcorper diam vitae, consequat ipsum. Sed maximus congue ipsum, id euismod arcu porttitor eget. Nam quis egestas risus. Sed quam augue, vestibulum ut lectus in, posuere interdum turpis. Cras ac egestas sem. Aliquam vitae sem ut tortor auctor aliquet a eu orci. Vivamus eu maximus lorem, placerat feugiat nisl. Suspendisse venenatis interdum tortor, non pellentesque dui suscipit nec. In imperdiet tincidunt convallis. In fringilla nisl id dolor aliquam, ut posuere felis efficitur. Aliquam id blandit elit, in euismod ante. Sed malesuada nisl ornare elementum ullamcorper. In vestibulum gravida libero, a finibus mi gravida eu.

Aenean ullamcorper arcu sed leo sodales commodo. Aenean in ex vitae lacus vulputate blandit sed eu sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at orci vel arcu volutpat eleifend. Quisque eu erat at lacus fringilla tincidunt. Nunc enim purus, posuere quis est a, pretium tincidunt est. Vivamus suscipit, neque quis aliquet dignissim, nisi lectus varius nisl, vel eleifend justo leo vel augue. Phasellus feugiat volutpat turpis. In eros mi, pulvinar vitae massa vel, vulputate varius nunc. Aliquam consectetur tortor vehicula, finibus felis tempor, hendrerit risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam pretium porttitor ante ac convallis. Nunc sollicitudin sed nunc congue dictum. Morbi pellentesque turpis bibendum turpis consectetur molestie. Integer luctus non libero vitae congue. Aliquam ex odio, vulputate interdum sagittis et, lobortis interdum eros.

Aliquam tincidunt rhoncus turpis et sagittis. Etiam ullamcorper augue id interdum fermentum. Morbi vitae nisi lorem. Proin a cursus nibh, at facilisis dolor. Nulla eu urna viverra dolor sodales mattis non et est. Quisque sagittis arcu tempor, aliquam mauris ut, porttitor velit. Phasellus nec tempus urna, eu aliquet ante. Vestibulum ultricies metus eu arcu pellentesque gravida. Curabitur ac mollis lorem. Donec ullamcorper viverra dolor, id ultrices urna fringilla at. Nulla placerat leo sed vulputate feugiat. Maecenas at consectetur massa, eget mollis enim. Quisque felis nisl, blandit sit amet ultrices vel, ultrices at justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Curabitur commodo tellus vitae ex egestas, in maximus ligula pellentesque. Vestibulum dictum metus non magna sollicitudin ornare. Etiam consequat placerat eros, nec lobortis massa gravida id. Suspendisse elementum risus ac semper faucibus. Suspendisse ut interdum tortor. Aliquam ornare imperdiet dapibus. Ut lacinia consequat metus, at accumsan mauris pretium sed. In nec congue ante. Nam nec arcu vitae eros iaculis molestie. Phasellus vitae eleifend nunc, tincidunt suscipit eros. Suspendisse leo ligula, tempor in sagittis ut, commodo id purus. Mauris nec lectus augue. Phasellus in tellus erat.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisl iaculis sem ullamcorper laoreet vel posuere urna. Sed venenatis sem quis mattis auctor. Proin a urna risus. Maecenas eu purus semper, semper nibh a, pharetra est. Nunc ultrices elit convallis tristique consequat. Phasellus placerat velit sapien, vitae rhoncus arcu ultrices at. In sodales sodales lorem, vitae efficitur arcu pulvinar ac. Nam finibus luctus luctus. Ut aliquet ullamcorper tempor. Nullam a malesuada est, rhoncus elementum nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam lobortis pulvinar est eu dignissim.

Aenean pretium enim et libero vehicula, a scelerisque enim viverra. Phasellus ullamcorper tortor ac nisl ornare, eu volutpat libero efficitur. Vivamus vitae nisi viverra, ullamcorper diam vitae, consequat ipsum. Sed maximus congue ipsum, id euismod arcu porttitor eget. Nam quis egestas risus. Sed quam augue, vestibulum ut lectus in, posuere interdum turpis. Cras ac egestas sem. Aliquam vitae sem ut tortor auctor aliquet a eu orci. Vivamus eu maximus lorem, placerat feugiat nisl. Suspendisse venenatis interdum tortor, non pellentesque dui suscipit nec. In imperdiet tincidunt convallis. In fringilla nisl id dolor aliquam, ut posuere felis efficitur. Aliquam id blandit elit, in euismod ante. Sed malesuada nisl ornare elementum ullamcorper. In vestibulum gravida libero, a finibus mi gravida eu.

Aenean ullamcorper arcu sed leo sodales commodo. Aenean in ex vitae lacus vulputate blandit sed eu sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at orci vel arcu volutpat eleifend. Quisque eu erat at lacus fringilla tincidunt. Nunc enim purus, posuere quis est a, pretium tincidunt est. Vivamus suscipit, neque quis aliquet dignissim, nisi lectus varius nisl, vel eleifend justo leo vel augue. Phasellus feugiat volutpat turpis. In eros mi, pulvinar vitae massa vel, vulputate varius nunc. Aliquam consectetur tortor vehicula, finibus felis tempor, hendrerit risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam pretium porttitor ante ac convallis. Nunc sollicitudin sed nunc congue dictum. Morbi pellentesque turpis bibendum turpis consectetur molestie. Integer luctus non libero vitae congue. Aliquam ex odio, vulputate interdum sagittis et, lobortis interdum eros.

Aliquam tincidunt rhoncus turpis et sagittis. Etiam ullamcorper augue id interdum fermentum. Morbi vitae nisi lorem. Proin a cursus nibh, at facilisis dolor. Nulla eu urna viverra dolor sodales mattis non et est. Quisque sagittis arcu tempor, aliquam mauris ut, porttitor velit. Phasellus nec tempus urna, eu aliquet ante. Vestibulum ultricies metus eu arcu pellentesque gravida. Curabitur ac mollis lorem. Donec ullamcorper viverra dolor, id ultrices urna fringilla at. Nulla placerat leo sed vulputate feugiat. Maecenas at consectetur massa, eget mollis enim. Quisque felis nisl, blandit sit amet ultrices vel, ultrices at justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Curabitur commodo tellus vitae ex egestas, in maximus ligula pellentesque. Vestibulum dictum metus non magna sollicitudin ornare. Etiam consequat placerat eros, nec lobortis massa gravida id. Suspendisse elementum risus ac semper faucibus. Suspendisse ut interdum tortor. Aliquam ornare imperdiet dapibus. Ut lacinia consequat metus, at accumsan mauris pretium sed. In nec congue ante. Nam nec arcu vitae eros iaculis molestie. Phasellus vitae eleifend nunc, tincidunt suscipit eros. Suspendisse leo ligula, tempor in sagittis ut, commodo id purus. Mauris nec lectus augue. Phasellus in tellus erat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an answer purely made out of css.
Using calc property of css you can achieve this thing easily using CSS.**

```css
*{
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
body,html{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.header {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 30px;
  position:fixed; /* setting to be at top always */
  width:100%; /* fix pposition will require a width to occupy space */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  
}

.nav {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 7rem;
  position:fixed; /* position fix to keep it on position */
  top: 30px; /* equal to height of header */
 
}

.sticky-nav {

   height: calc(100vh - 30px); /* calculating height according to browser height subtracting the top height of header*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
}

.content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  padding:5px; 
  padding-left:7rem; /* padding left = width of 7rem*/
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="sticky-nav">
      <p>Item 1</p>
      <p>Item 2</p>
      <p>Item 3</p>
      <p>Item 4</p>
      <p>Item 5</p>
      <p>Item 6</p>
      <p>Item 7</p>
      <p>Item 8</p>
      <p>Item 9</p>
      <p>Item 10</p>
      <p>Item 11</p>
      <p>Item 12</p>
      <p>Item 13</p>
      <p>Item 14</p>
      <p>Item 15</p>
      <p>Item 16</p>
      <p>Item 17</p>
      <p>Item 18</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisl iaculis sem ullamcorper laoreet vel posuere urna. Sed venenatis sem quis mattis auctor. Proin a urna risus. Maecenas eu purus semper, semper nibh a, pharetra est. Nunc ultrices elit convallis tristique consequat. Phasellus placerat velit sapien, vitae rhoncus arcu ultrices at. In sodales sodales lorem, vitae efficitur arcu pulvinar ac. Nam finibus luctus luctus. Ut aliquet ullamcorper tempor. Nullam a malesuada est, rhoncus elementum nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam lobortis pulvinar est eu dignissim.

Aenean pretium enim et libero vehicula, a scelerisque enim viverra. Phasellus ullamcorper tortor ac nisl ornare, eu volutpat libero efficitur. Vivamus vitae nisi viverra, ullamcorper diam vitae, consequat ipsum. Sed maximus congue ipsum, id euismod arcu porttitor eget. Nam quis egestas risus. Sed quam augue, vestibulum ut lectus in, posuere interdum turpis. Cras ac egestas sem. Aliquam vitae sem ut tortor auctor aliquet a eu orci. Vivamus eu maximus lorem, placerat feugiat nisl. Suspendisse venenatis interdum tortor, non pellentesque dui suscipit nec. In imperdiet tincidunt convallis. In fringilla nisl id dolor aliquam, ut posuere felis efficitur. Aliquam id blandit elit, in euismod ante. Sed malesuada nisl ornare elementum ullamcorper. In vestibulum gravida libero, a finibus mi gravida eu.

Aenean ullamcorper arcu sed leo sodales commodo. Aenean in ex vitae lacus vulputate blandit sed eu sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at orci vel arcu volutpat eleifend. Quisque eu erat at lacus fringilla tincidunt. Nunc enim purus, posuere quis est a, pretium tincidunt est. Vivamus suscipit, neque quis aliquet dignissim, nisi lectus varius nisl, vel eleifend justo leo vel augue. Phasellus feugiat volutpat turpis. In eros mi, pulvinar vitae massa vel, vulputate varius nunc. Aliquam consectetur tortor vehicula, finibus felis tempor, hendrerit risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam pretium porttitor ante ac convallis. Nunc sollicitudin sed nunc congue dictum. Morbi pellentesque turpis bibendum turpis consectetur molestie. Integer luctus non libero vitae congue. Aliquam ex odio, vulputate interdum sagittis et, lobortis interdum eros.

Aliquam tincidunt rhoncus turpis et sagittis. Etiam ullamcorper augue id interdum fermentum. Morbi vitae nisi lorem. Proin a cursus nibh, at facilisis dolor. Nulla eu urna viverra dolor sodales mattis non et est. Quisque sagittis arcu tempor, aliquam mauris ut, porttitor velit. Phasellus nec tempus urna, eu aliquet ante. Vestibulum ultricies metus eu arcu pellentesque gravida. Curabitur ac mollis lorem. Donec ullamcorper viverra dolor, id ultrices urna fringilla at. Nulla placerat leo sed vulputate feugiat. Maecenas at consectetur massa, eget mollis enim. Quisque felis nisl, blandit sit amet ultrices vel, ultrices at justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Curabitur commodo tellus vitae ex egestas, in maximus ligula pellentesque. Vestibulum dictum metus non magna sollicitudin ornare. Etiam consequat placerat eros, nec lobortis massa gravida id. Suspendisse elementum risus ac semper faucibus. Suspendisse ut interdum tortor. Aliquam ornare imperdiet dapibus. Ut lacinia consequat metus, at accumsan mauris pretium sed. In nec congue ante. Nam nec arcu vitae eros iaculis molestie. Phasellus vitae eleifend nunc, tincidunt suscipit eros. Suspendisse leo ligula, tempor in sagittis ut, commodo id purus. Mauris nec lectus augue. Phasellus in tellus erat.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisl iaculis sem ullamcorper laoreet vel posuere urna. Sed venenatis sem quis mattis auctor. Proin a urna risus. Maecenas eu purus semper, semper nibh a, pharetra est. Nunc ultrices elit convallis tristique consequat. Phasellus placerat velit sapien, vitae rhoncus arcu ultrices at. In sodales sodales lorem, vitae efficitur arcu pulvinar ac. Nam finibus luctus luctus. Ut aliquet ullamcorper tempor. Nullam a malesuada est, rhoncus elementum nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam lobortis pulvinar est eu dignissim.

Aenean pretium enim et libero vehicula, a scelerisque enim viverra. Phasellus ullamcorper tortor ac nisl ornare, eu volutpat libero efficitur. Vivamus vitae nisi viverra, ullamcorper diam vitae, consequat ipsum. Sed maximus congue ipsum, id euismod arcu porttitor eget. Nam quis egestas risus. Sed quam augue, vestibulum ut lectus in, posuere interdum turpis. Cras ac egestas sem. Aliquam vitae sem ut tortor auctor aliquet a eu orci. Vivamus eu maximus lorem, placerat feugiat nisl. Suspendisse venenatis interdum tortor, non pellentesque dui suscipit nec. In imperdiet tincidunt convallis. In fringilla nisl id dolor aliquam, ut posuere felis efficitur. Aliquam id blandit elit, in euismod ante. Sed malesuada nisl ornare elementum ullamcorper. In vestibulum gravida libero, a finibus mi gravida eu.

Aenean ullamcorper arcu sed leo sodales commodo. Aenean in ex vitae lacus vulputate blandit sed eu sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at orci vel arcu volutpat eleifend. Quisque eu erat at lacus fringilla tincidunt. Nunc enim purus, posuere quis est a, pretium tincidunt est. Vivamus suscipit, neque quis aliquet dignissim, nisi lectus varius nisl, vel eleifend justo leo vel augue. Phasellus feugiat volutpat turpis. In eros mi, pulvinar vitae massa vel, vulputate varius nunc. Aliquam consectetur tortor vehicula, finibus felis tempor, hendrerit risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam pretium porttitor ante ac convallis. Nunc sollicitudin sed nunc congue dictum. Morbi pellentesque turpis bibendum turpis consectetur molestie. Integer luctus non libero vitae congue. Aliquam ex odio, vulputate interdum sagittis et, lobortis interdum eros.

Aliquam tincidunt rhoncus turpis et sagittis. Etiam ullamcorper augue id interdum fermentum. Morbi vitae nisi lorem. Proin a cursus nibh, at facilisis dolor. Nulla eu urna viverra dolor sodales mattis non et est. Quisque sagittis arcu tempor, aliquam mauris ut, porttitor velit. Phasellus nec tempus urna, eu aliquet ante. Vestibulum ultricies metus eu arcu pellentesque gravida. Curabitur ac mollis lorem. Donec ullamcorper viverra dolor, id ultrices urna fringilla at. Nulla placerat leo sed vulputate feugiat. Maecenas at consectetur massa, eget mollis enim. Quisque felis nisl, blandit sit amet ultrices vel, ultrices at justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Curabitur commodo tellus vitae ex egestas, in maximus ligula pellentesque. Vestibulum dictum metus non magna sollicitudin ornare. Etiam consequat placerat eros, nec lobortis massa gravida id. Suspendisse elementum risus ac semper faucibus. Suspendisse ut interdum tortor. Aliquam ornare imperdiet dapibus. Ut lacinia consequat metus, at accumsan mauris pretium sed. In nec congue ante. Nam nec arcu vitae eros iaculis molestie. Phasellus vitae eleifend nunc, tincidunt suscipit eros. Suspendisse leo ligula, tempor in sagittis ut, commodo id purus. Mauris nec lectus augue. Phasellus in tellus erat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't want the header to be fixed. That's why it's difficult. Maybe that's not possible with CSS. I will edit my question to be more precise.